# SharedPreferences - Firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou realizando login normalmente porém quado fecho aplicação, volta para tela de login. Estou tentado executar sharedPreferences porém não tenho êxito.

```
public static final String PREF_NAME = "LoginActivityPreferences";
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

// Metodo onCreate
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(LoginActivity.this);
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

// Metodo shared
private void sharedPreferences(String email, String password) {


    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

            if (user != null) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class));

            } else {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("email", email);
                editor.putString("password", password);
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
            }
}

 // Metodo de login email e senha
 private void singInEmailSenha(final String email, final String password) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        sharedPreferences(email, password);
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que guardar o valor recebido quando entra na condição caso o usuário exista. Veja:

```
mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
if (user != null) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("email", email);
    editor.putString("password", password);
    editor.commit();

    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class));

} else {

    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
}
```

Comment: Mesmo assim esta acontecendo a mesma coisa, volta para tela de login. Assim tenho que pegar usuário logado para poder guardar no sharedPreferences.

Comment: @DouglasWilliam foi feito confusão na condição; Veja

Comment: @DouglasWilliam fiz uma alteração. Dê uma olhada... você tem mesmo que guardados os dados quando o usuário existe e não quando ele não existe.

Comment: Mesmo assim esta acontecendo a mesma coisa, volta para tela de login

Comment: @DouglasWilliam debuga seu código e veja como está chegando o user, se realmente está salvando os dados nessa  variável

Answer (score 0):

Você tem algum campo de "Mantenha-me logado"?

Caso a resposta for SIM, faça mais um:

```
editor.putBoolean("permanecer", false);
```

E ai no onCreate da sua tela de Login, você verifica se esse valor ta como true, caso tiver já entra na tela principal, senão, você fican a tela de login

Comment: E caso a reposta for não(nao tenho um campo de checkbox pra permanecer logado), você pode usar o mesmo esquema, só que la na sua aplicaçao, na tela principal, seria interessante ter uma opção do usuário deslogar OU sair